# Basic Authenticated HTTP Connection To SSAS Is Very Slow

Tags: ssas, basic-authentication, datapump

I've configured my SSAS connection to use HTTP and everything works fine. The problem is that the connection is very slow when I'm using just Basic Authentication and passing the username and password as part of the ConnectionString. If I change MSMDPUMP.dll IIS app to use Anonymous Authentication, the connection works "as fast" as without HTTP. Again, the problem is that Anonymous Authentication is not acceptable for me and I really need Basic Authenticated security.

What's happening with the Basic Authentication and is there a way to make it faster? The solution is unusable at the moment.

Comment: I'm noticing the same problem.  Connecting to SSAS through IIS using Basic Authentication is extremely slow.  The MDX query returns in 9ms (as shown in SQL Profiler) but the whole request takes over 500ms.  This isn't a huge problem if running just 1 MDX query, but some of our endpoints run 20 MDX queries, resulting in an unbearably slow endpoint.